# Customize the notification center appearance

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I try to make an ubuntu respin (ubuntu 20.04) and everything works fine except one thing :

I don't like the "arrowy" look of the notification center. Here's what I'm talking about :

[image: The notification center in ubuntu 20.04]

I recently try Zorin OS 16, wich is also based on ubuntu 20.04, and noticed that there is now "arrowy" thing on their distro :

[image: The notification center in Zorin 16]

Is there a way to change that ? Removing this "arrow" ?

Comment: I need to refer it in the "tag" section of my post ? I'm new sorry

Comment: I personally don't see your question as on-topic as you're trying to create a non-Ubuntu distro, but given you have a system that does what you want, I'd compare what the off-topic Zorin is doing (what is being used, etc), with what is in the standard Ubuntu (what you don't want) for clues on what to change.

Comment: No, I'm trying to create an ubuntu respin (I changed distro by respin on my question), I just want to change the theme, and remove/add some packages, but I was wondering if this notification center style was customisable or not

Comment: That's easily possible. You want to remove the arrow for default theme that ships with Ubuntu 20.04 or do you have any other theme??

Comment: I just want to remove it, I want it to look (and I'm just talking about the overall shape, not the colors etc) like the Zorin one

Comment: Yes that's possible but do you have custom theme or do you want it to edit from default theme that ships with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: If the solution works for both default and custom it's okay for me, I don't have custom theme right know but maybe later so

Comment: Ok in that case you need to edit for each custom theme you are going to use. I will write the code in answer in some time.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Almost done.. Do you want it specifically to remove for Notification Center or for all the top bar?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhZXm.gif

Comment: For all the top bar, I look at your gif and this look nice ! Just one thing, is it possible to make a bit more sticky to the top bar ? Right now there is a little gap, can it be removed ? If it's not possible that's not a huge problem, you have already done a perfect job !

Answer (score 1):

I Dont have Ubuntu 20.04 Installed. I have tested this in gnome-shell 40.
In any gnome-shell theme for your version. Searching the below content and editing it to your preferred values will bring the changes you are looking for.

```
/* Popovers/Menus */
.popup-menu-boxpointer, .candidate-popup-boxpointer {
  -arrow-border-radius: 12px;
  -arrow-background-color: #353535;
  -arrow-border-width: 0px;
  -arrow-border-color: #202020;
  -arrow-base: 0px; # I have edited this
  -arrow-rise: 0px; # I have edited this
  -arrow-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

[image]

Comment: I love it ! Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try that as soon as possible !